# Counting empty cells inside of a data matrix xlsx

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have 3 columns with data inside an excel document.
On the middle column for example, there are some empty spaces without data.

I've created an object to retrieve data into it, in a sorted manner by rows.

Problem that I have encountered is that I cannot store the empty cells as empty, inside my object, and I'm losing data with this problem.
So like in the below example, I'm getting only data from the rows that has something written on every column.. if one column is empty, nothing returns.

[image]

I'm getting the cell value on the generic way :

```
public static Object getCellValue(Cell cell)
{

    Object cellValue = null;
    if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING){

        cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();

    }else if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC){

        cellValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();

    }else if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BOOLEAN){

        cellValue = cell.getBooleanCellValue();

    }else if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BLANK){

        cellValue = "";

    }
    return cellValue;

}
```

Creating the object of cells. It's very important to order the output as for example : column 1 row 1 must be strictly assign to column 2 and 3 on the same row .I have to keep them in their order, even if a cell is blank/ empty, inside the data matrix.

```
public class ColumnsOrder {

 private String fristColumn;
 private String secondColumn;
 private String thirdColumn;

 public ColumnsOrder() {

 }

 public ColumnsOrder(String fristColumn) {
    super();
    this.fristColumn = fristColumn;
 }

 public ColumnsOrder(String fristColumn, String secondColumn) {
    super();
    this.fristColumn = fristColumn;
    this.secondColumn = secondColumn;
 }

 public ColumnsOrder(String fristColumn, String secondColumn,
        String thirdColumn) {
    super();
    this.fristColumn = fristColumn;
    this.secondColumn = secondColumn;
    this.thirdColumn = thirdColumn;
 }

 public String getFristColumn() {
    return fristColumn;
 }

 public String getSecondColumn() {
    return secondColumn;
 }

 public String getThirdColumn() {
    return thirdColumn;
 }

}
```

Here I'm taking out data from xlsx, and probabily here I'm doing something wrong.

```
for( rowIndex = rowStart; rowIndex <= rowEnd; rowIndex++ ) {

                Cell cellOne = null;
                Cell cellTwo = null;
                Cell cellThree = null;

                row = sheet.getRow( rowIndex );

                if (row != null ) {
// getting data from each column
                            cellOne     =  (Cell) (( !CheckIfCellIsEmpty.isCellEmpty( row.getCell(0) ) ) ? row.getCell(0) : "" );
                            cellTwo     =  (Cell) (( !CheckIfCellIsEmpty.isCellEmpty( row.getCell(1) ) ) ? row.getCell(1) : " ");
                            cellThree   =  (Cell) (( !CheckIfCellIsEmpty.isCellEmpty( row.getCell(2) ) ) ? row.getCell(2) : " ");

                            // Creating the object using its constructor
                            columnsExcelTemp.add( new ColumnsOrder( 
                                                                    (String)GetCellValue.getCellValue(cellOne), 
                                                                    (String)GetCellValue.getCellValue(cellTwo),
                                                                    (String)GetCellValue.getCellValue(cellThree) 
                                                                  ) 
                                                );
    }
workbook.close();
}
```

Check if isEmpty function

```
public static boolean isCellEmpty(final Cell cell) 
{

    if (cell == null )
    {
        return true;
    }

    /*
    if ( cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BLANK ) { 
        return false;
    }

    if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    if( cell.getStringCellValue().isEmpty() )
    {
        return false;
    }
    */

    return false;

}
```

Comment: What is your end goal? there might be a different way to approach this scenario

Comment: A list with objects that contain any row of this excel data-table, even if one of the columns are empty ( inside that area )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I've solved the problem with a built - in function inside of Apache POI libraries.

```
                            cellOne     =  row.getCell( 0, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK );
                            cellTwo     =  row.getCell( 1, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK );
                            cellThree   =  row.getCell( 2, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK );
```

**Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK** added as second parameter give BLANK value to the null cells inside my table, which solves the actual problem.

***If anyone need help in Java - Apache POI, write me a comment here.***

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that what you see as an empty cell in a Excel sheet can be either a cell with a value like '' or it can be non existant to Excel. If you use row.getCell() always check if it is null!

Comment: I'm checking with public static boolean isCellEmpty(final Cell cell)